# JavaScript Calculator not working properly, not sure which part of my code is incorrect

Tags: javascript, function, methods, calculator, operation

I've created a calculator using html and css, the programming language I chose to manipulate my html elements is JavaScript but none of my code seems to be working, I'm not sure where I went wrong.

None of the buttons work, neither do my operations that I'm attempting to do, it seems like I'm missing something.

can anyone please help me identify the problems with my code?
thank you so much!!

```
    class Calculator {
    constructor(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement) {
        this.previousOperandTextElement = previousOperandTextElement
        this.currentOperandTextElemement = currentOperandTextElement
        this.clear()
    }

    clear() {
        this.currentOperand = ''
        this.previousOperand = ''
        this.operation = undefined
    }

    delete() {
        this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString().slice(0, -1)

    }
    appendNumber(number) {
        if (number === '.' && this.currentOperand.includes('.')) return
        this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString() + number.toString()

    }
    chooseOperation(operation) {
        if (this.currentOperand === '.') return
        if (this.previousOperand !== '') {
            this.compute()
        }
        this.operation = operation
        this.previousOperand = this.currentOperand
        this.currentOperand = ''
    }

    compute() {
        let computation
        const prev = parseFloat(this.previousOperand)
        const current = parseFloat(this.currentOperand)
        if (isNan(prev) || isNan(current)) return
        switch (this.operation) {
            case '+':
                computation = prev + current
                break
            case '-':
               computation = prev - current
                break
            case '*':
                computation = prev * current
                break
            case '÷':
                computation = prev / current
                break
            default:
                return
        }
        this.currentOperand = computation
        this.operation = undefined
        this.previousOperand = ''
    }

    getDisplayNumber(number) {
        const stringNumber = number.toString()
        const integerDigits = parseFloat(stringNumber.split('.')[0])
        const decimalDigits = stringNumber.split('.')[1]
        let integerDisplay
        if (isNan(integerDigits)) {
            integerDisplay = ''
       } else {
            integerDisplay integerDigits.toLocalString('en', {
                maximumFractionDigits: 0
            })
        }
        if (decimalDigits != null) {
            return `${integerDisplay}.${decimalDigits}`
        } else {
            return integerDisplay
        }

    }

    updateDisplay() {
        this.currentOperandTextElemement.innerText =
            this.getDisplayNumber(this.currentOperand)
        if (this.operation != null) {
            this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText =
            `${this.getDisplayNumber(previousOperand)} ${this.operation}`
        } else {
            this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText = ''
        }
    }
}


const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]')
const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operation]')
const equalsButton = document.querySelector('[data-equals]')
const deleteButton = document.querySelector('[data-delete]')
const allClearButton = document.querySelector('[data-all-clear]')
const previousOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-previous-operand]')
const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-current-operand]')

const calculator = new Calculator(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement)

numberButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText)
        calculator.updateDisplay()
    })
})

operationButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        calculator.chooseOperation(button.innerText)
        calculator.updateDisplay()
    })
})

equalsButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
    calculator.compute()
    calculator.updateDisplay()
})

allClearButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
    calculator.clear()
    calculator.updateDisplay()
})

deleteButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
   calculator.delete()
    calculator.updateDisplay()
})
```

Comment: say you start pressing 12+3.2= - what does it appear in the console? Update the question with a copy/paste of the console after you do these.

Comment: Hey @MadaManu, I got it to work, I had simple errors like for example, I wrote "isNan" as oppose to "isNaN" and I missed an "=" sign between integerDisplay and integerDigits.toLocaleString, I also forgot to add an "e" to "Locale", basically silly case sensitive errors, thanks for your help!!